# Adding Outlet to Switch

Tags: switch, receptacle

I'm trying to add an outlet to this switch box, I live in the UK and tried to diagram this the best I can of what I can see.
How do I connect a T+E cable (attached to an outlet) to this system?
[image]

Comment: For any switch/lamp group, only one of those places can be tapped for power, and you don't get to decide which one that is.  That is decided by the wiring.   So running a cable to a switch and *expecting* to be able to tap it, is a lost cause.   Also, UK lighting circuits are often 6A - too small for receptacles.

Comment: What size breaker is this circuit on? Also, can you update your diagram to show how the wires are grouped into *cables* and/or post photos of the back of the backbox? That information's rather important for us trying to decode the situation